# How to overlay a section title on \incgraph full page image?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, overlays, includegraphics, fullpage

Is there any way to get a section title, which is included and linked in the TOC, overlaying on a full page image, inserted with `\incgraph[]{image}?`

Both tikz and incgraph is included

```
\usepackage{incgraph,tikz}
```

I can easily get the page number added with:

```
\incgraph[documentpaper,overlay page number at bottom][angle=90,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Appendices/ServiceBlueprint_AcquisitionOfBike.png}
```

However I need a section on the same page as the image (or just a reference in the TOC)

Currently `\section{Service Blueprint}` goes to the next page, like illustrated below.

[image: Overlaying section linked to TOC is what i need. Currently the section goes to next page as illustrated]